# I have issue with jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery

i m working on jQuery accordion and i got the code from this [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) accordion working perfectly but the issue is i want to open 2nd tab by default when user come over my page i want to show them the content in second tab .

plaese help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active

Comment: at the same link click "option tab" -> click "active"

Comment: i'd like to help, but unless you help us see your code snippet, then we can't do anything to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

View this link and open option tab may be help you

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active

```
Initialize a accordion with the active option specified.
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
Get or set the active option, after init.
//getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [active](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active) option:

```
$('.selector').accordion({ active: 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't have two tabs open at the same time with an accordion according the documentation.